# Pseudo-code in latex

Tags: algorithms, code, pseudocode

Could you help me to write this pseudo-code in latex please?
  [image]

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: Perhaps the `algorithmic` package from the **algorithms** bundle?

Comment: or `algorithm2e`